# Typescript Libraries not being included in compiling/Type checking Mocha tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

Attempting to use the Typescript declared type "File" (lib.dom.d.ts) in my Mocha test (see below) and when ts-node compiles using tsconfig.json file, the appropriate library is not being included/checked.

I have both es6 and dom libraries referenced in the "lib" tsconfig.json array (they both have a declared File type).  (I have verified that the tsconfig.json is being used and there is no other tsconfig.json)

--ERROR--

`ReferenceError: File is not defined`

-- NPM script --

`"mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register tests/**/*.tests.ts"`

--Test---
`

```
  describe("SendFile Endpoint", () => {
       const file = new File(["test"], "filename"); //< -- File ref
       const formData: FormData;
       const error = new Error("error occurred sending file");
       const responseString = JSON.stringify({postId: 1});
       .....
```

`

-- tsconfig.json --
`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "es6", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "types" : [ "node" , "reflect-metadata"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/index.d.ts",
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?